# implementing Facade Pattern Not working in .Net Core 5 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, model-view-controller, facade

I am Completely New in Facade Pattern and I am trying to implement a real example . Here what I have done.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 MVC .Net Core 5, With Clean Architecture.

I have 3 Services for User Entity. This is a IUserFacade which is located in Application Layer

```
   public interface IUserFacade
   {
      EditUserService EditUserService { get; }
      RegisterUserService RegisterUserService { get; }
      RemoveUserService RemoveUserService { get; }
   }
```

The implementation of IUserFacade is Application Layer as following

```
   public class UserFacade : IUserFacade
{
    private readonly IDataBaseContext _context;

    public UserFacade(IDataBaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    private EditUserService _editUserService;
    public EditUserService EditUserService
    {
        get
        {
            return _editUserService = _editUserService ?? new EditUserService(_context);
        }
    }

    private RegisterUserService _registerUserService;
    public RegisterUserService RegisterUserService
    {
        get
        {
            return _registerUserService = _registerUserService ?? new RegisterUserService(_context);
        }
    }

    private RemoveUserService _removeUserService;
    public RemoveUserService RemoveUserService
    {
        get
        {
            return _removeUserService = _removeUserService ?? new RemoveUserService(_context);
        }
    }

}
```

And this is what I have added in configureService of startup

```
  services.AddScoped<IUserFacade, UserFacade>();
```

and The EditUserService , RemoveUserService  , RegisterUserService  are implemented in Application Layer
But when I run the project, I receive this error message

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Bugeto_Store.Application.Services.Users.Commands.RgegisterUser.IRegisterUserService' while attempting to activate 'EndPoint.Site.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UsersController'.

But When I remove the Facade pattern IUserFacade and UserFacade and replace

```
   services.AddScoped<IRegisterUserService,  RegisterUserService>();
   services.AddScoped<IRemoveUserService,  RemoveUserService>();
   services.AddScoped<IEditUserService,  EditUserService>();
```

instead of this

```
   services.AddScoped<IUserFacade, UserFacade>();
```

everu
thing works find. how can I trace the error?

Comment: Do you have a typo in the interface? IUserFacad <-> IUserFacade once with the 'e' once without.

Comment: @rachri: I mistyped,  that was not the case

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that somewhere in your application, namely `EndPoint.Site.Areas.Admin.Controllers.UsersController`, you're still trying to inject the `IRegisterUserService` directly in the constructor, without your facade.

Also, since you're trying to grasp the facade pattern, I have a small suggestion.

```
public interface IUserFacade
{
   EditUserService EditUserService { get; }
   RegisterUserService RegisterUserService { get; }
   RemoveUserService RemoveUserService { get; }
}
```

Here you have concrete implementations of your interfaces. What's the point of facade if you're not even hiding concrete implementations? Even if you change that for interfaces (e.g. `EditUserService` -> `IEditUserService`) it's still going to be more like an abstract factory. The facade is supposed to hide some complexity, by exposing these services you're not hiding anything.

Your facade should provide an interface for accessing the application layer and hide as many calls to the application layer from the outside as it is possible, then it will hide the application layer's complexities. It should be a client that your API uses and the API should have no knowledge about the application layer's internal stuff abstracted by your facade.